# Как получить из исходного массива и двух объектов результирующий массив учитывая некоторые условия?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив объектов одинаковой структуры.
Поля в объекте могут быть разными, объектом (не известной степени вложенности), Date, string, number, boolean.

```
let inputArrayData = [{
   fullName: {
      surname: 'xxx',
      firstName: 'yyy',
      middleName: 'zzz',
      isHuman: true,
      Date: Mar 12 2012,
      other: "1"
   }
}, {
   fullName: {
      surname: 'XXX',
      firstName: 'YYY',
      middleName: 'ZZZ',
      isHuman: false,
      Date: Mar 8 2012,
      other: "2"
   }
}];
```

Есть объект такой же структуры, но с типами полей boolean.
Используется для задания правил преобразований (если значение поля true - то поле должно быть в результирующем массиве)

```
let configArrayData = {
   fullName: {
     surname: true,
     firstName: true,
     middleName: false,
     isHuman: true,
     Date: true,
     other: true
  }
}
```

Есть объект с типами полей string, в которых хранятся локализованные заголовки полей.

```
let localizationConfig = {
  "fullName.surname": "Прізвище",
  "fullName.firstName": "Ім'я",
  "fullName.middleName": "По-батькові",
  "fullName.isHuman": "Чи людина?",
  "fullName.Date": "Дата",
  "fullName.other": ""
}
```

Необходимо написать код, который на основе вышеописанных объектов создаст массив объектов
следующей структуры:*/

```
let outputArray = [{
   name: "Прізвище",
   value1: "xxx",
   value2: "XXX"
}, {
   name: "Ім'я",
   value1: "yyy",
   value2: "YYY"
}, {
   name: "По-батькові",
   value1: "zzz",
   value2: "ZZZ"
}, {
   name: "Чи людина?",
   value1: "Так",
   value2: "Ні"
}, {
   name: "Дата",
   value1: "12.03.2012",
   value2: "08.03.2012"
}{
   name: "other",
   value1: "1",
   value2: "2"
}]
```

Если для поля отсутствует локализация, то вместо локализации необходимо вывести название этого поля.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: думаю нужна примерно такая функция, которая принимает массив и два объекта, перебирать надо с помощью forEach(), дальше с логикой туговато если честно
function buildResultData(inputArrayData, configArrayData, localizationConfig) {
  

   return outputArray;
}

Comment: Суть проблемы и попытку ее решения, нужно писать **в вопросе** - без этого, вопрос может набрать (заслуженные) минусы/тревоги/голоса за закрытие (как несоответствующий тематике stackoverflow). Просто цель ресурса в том чтобы приносить пользу сообществу - а когда проблема неясна, то и польза решения будет равна нулю.

Comment: Я вот затрудняюсь сказать, в чем собственно проблема задачи. Это же просто набор свойств в объекты, по сути))

Comment: проблема задачи в том, что бы её решить, я недавно закончил курсы, по этому ещё не волшебник, а только учусь )
я пытаюсь решить её через рекурсивный обход массива, что тоже с непривычки вызывает определенные трудности

Comment: Выкладывать было пока нечего. Как появится мало-мальски начало решения через рекурсию, выложу. Если можно вопрос к Вашему решению: не выводится в результат поле и значение: "name": "Дата" и элемент other - это моё упущение, (я исправил это добавив недостающие элементы в условие и поправив Ваш код - сорри) прошу прощения если что, это мой первый пост.
Так же не реализовано условие: "Если для поля отсутствует локализация, то вместо локализации необходимо вывести название этого поля. И если поле boolean должно выводиться «Так»/«Ні»

Comment: Все-таки нужно решение через рекурсию т.к. по условию «Поля в объекте могут не известной степени вложенности», что я не включил в условие посчитав по неопытности не важным – сори.

Comment: «Все-таки нужно решение через рекурсию» - тогда это другая задача, и подход к решению соответственно будет совсем другой. А изменения относительно булевых значений и полей без локализации, внесены в ответ.

Comment: Благодарю, но не совсем, на выходе (в части ниже) должно быть
{ "name": "Інше", "value1": "1", "value2": "other" }

Comment: Почему `"value2": "other"`?

Comment: Сорри, всё ок, это я спутал. Спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ решает задачу **в ее первичной формулировке** - до кардинального изменения ее сути в вопросе четвертой правкой (правка #5 учтена).

```js
// решение
const produceOutput = (data, dataCfg, l10nCfg, dataItemKey) => {
  if (!data.length) return []; 
  const l10nKeysRE = new RegExp(dataItemKey + '\.(.+)$', 'i');       // регулярка для преобразования ключей объекта локализации 
  const l10n = Object.keys(l10nCfg).reduce(                          // само преобразование
    (r, k) => ((r[k.match(l10nKeysRE)[1]] = l10nCfg[k]), r)
  , {}); 
  const l10nBool = ['Ні', 'Так']; 
  const result = Object.keys(data[0][dataItemKey])                   // подготовка объекта для аккумуляции данных
    .filter(k => dataCfg[dataItemKey][k])                            // возьмем только те ключи, которые отмечены в объекте конфига
    .reduce((r, k) => ((r[k] = { name: l10n[k] || k }), r), {});     // инициализируем объекты под данные, сразу добавив им строку из объекта локализации 
  data.forEach(({[dataItemKey]:itmData}, i) => {                     // далее просто добавляем значения в аккумулятор 
    Object.keys(itmData).forEach(k => {
      if (!result[k]) return; 
      let value = itmData[k]; 
      if (typeof itmData[k] === 'boolean')                           // ...преобразовав булевые - в локализованные строки
        value = l10nBool[+itmData[k]]; 
      result[k]['value' + (i + 1)] = value;
    }); 
  }); 
  return Object.keys(result).map(k => result[k]);                    // и вернем аккумулированные данные, преобразовав их объект в массив
}; 

// данные 
let inputArrayData = [{
   fullName: {
      surname: 'xxx',
      firstName: 'yyy',
      middleName: 'zzz',
      isHuman: true,
      date: 'Mar 12 2012',
      other: '1'
   }
}, {
   fullName: {
      surname: 'XXX',
      firstName: 'YYY',
      middleName: 'ZZZ',
      isHuman: false,
      date: 'Mar 8 2012',
      other: ''
   }
}];

let configArrayData = {
   fullName: {
     surname: true,
     firstName: true,
     middleName: false,
     isHuman: true,
     date: true, 
     other: true
  }
}; 

let localizationConfig = {
  "fullName.surname": "Прізвище",
  "fullName.firstName": "Ім'я",
  "fullName.middleName": "По-батькові",
  "fullName.isHuman": "Чи людина?",
  "fullName.date": "Дата", 
  "fullName.other": "Інше"
}; 

// тест
const output = produceOutput(
  inputArrayData, 
  configArrayData, 
  localizationConfig, 
  'fullName'
); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

Comment: yar85 благодарю за ответ, для меня это ценно, я обязательно разберу Ваш код и преобразую в знания!